# Formula for analytical finding ellipse and circle intersection points if exist

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, elliptic-equations

I need a formula that will give me all points of random ellipse and circle intersection (ok, not fully random, the center of circle is laying on ellipse curve)

I need step by step solution (algorithm how to find it) if this is possible.

Comment: As in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4309560) you look to await all from us. Please show that you have already worked on this issue.

Comment: You just asked this question yesterday. See link in comment above. I and one more gave answers on that question, which is same as this one. If this is not deleted I will probably downvote and/or vote to close this.

Comment: I don't think that having the center on the ellipse makes the problem simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a coordinate system where the $x$ axis is parallel to the ellipse major semiaxis, $y$ axis parallel to the ellipse minor semiaxis, and origin where they intersect ("center of ellipse").  If $a$ is the semi-major axis and $b$ the semi-minor axis, and
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{1a}\label{BtV1a}$$
Assuming we have a nondegenerate ellipse (an ellipse with nonzero area), then $a, b \gt 0$, and we can write above as
$$x^2 + \frac{a^2}{b^2} y^2 - a^2 = 0 \tag{1b}\label{BtV1b}$$

A circle of radius $r$ ($r \ge 0$) centered at $x = x_0$, $y = y_0$ fulfills
$$(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2 \tag{2a}\label{BtV2a}$$
which we can also expand into
$$x^2 - 2 x_0 x + y^2 - 2 y_0 y + x_0^2 + y_0^2 - r^2 = 0 \tag{2b}\label{BtV2b}$$

To find the point $(x, y)$ where the circle and the ellipse intersects, you need to solve the pair of equations, for example $\eqref{BtV1b}$ and $\eqref{BtV2b}$.

The system of equations has essentially form
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x^2 + C_1 y^2 + C_2 & = 0 \\
x^2 + C_3 x + y^2 + C_4 y + C_5 & = 0 \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{3}\label{BtV3}$$
where
$$C_1 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}, ~ 
C_2 = -a^2, ~
C_3 = -2 x_0, ~
C_4 = -2 y_0, ~
C_5 = x_0^2 + y_0^2 - r^2$$
One efficient way of solving $\eqref{BtV3}$ is to substract the first equation from the second, and solve for $x$. You'll find exactly one algebraic solution for $x$ (that depends on $y$).  Substitute it back into the first equation, and you have a quartic equation in $y$, which has zero, one, two, three, or four solutions.  Solve that, then substitute the numeric value or values of $y$ back into the algebraic solution for $x$, and you have the solution, which is either no intersection, one point of intersection, or two points of intersection.

Comment: "no intersection, one point of intersection, or two points of intersection" - there also possible three or four points

Comment: @Robotex: Very true!  I was specifically looking at the $a > b > r$ case.  Needs to be fixed, thank you!

Comment: Looks like your answer is best but I need to finish this calculations to prove it. There are a lot of math :(

Comment: I got the four roots of quadratic equation, but they are complex numbers. How to deal with it? Should I just drop the imaginary part and use the real only?

Comment: When I put the given y to equation for x, I got 0 in real part and some small number in imaginary part

Comment: Does this trick possible for hyperbola and ellipse intersection or hyperbola and hyperbola intersection?

Comment: Something wrong is here.

Here is my ellipse and circle:

var ellipse : Dictionary = {
        "a": 150,
        "b": 100
}

var circle : Dictionary = {
        "center": Vector2(120, 150),
        "radius": 100
}

[Result of calculations](https://ibb.co/DC2K5fZ)

The answers are fit of the quadratic equation (results with this roots are zero) but when I put the given x and y into equations of ellipse and circle I don't get the equality. I checked the calculations, looks like it correct.

Comment: Maybe I made mistake in calculations somewhere

Comment: Yes, it is working! But there is problem if x or y coordinate of circle's center is zero.

Comment: Why this method is not working if we replace ellipse by circle? I thought that circles are ellipses too

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the standard equation of the ellipse, $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, choose the centre of the circle to correspond to the parameter value $\theta$,  so the equation of the circle with this centre and radius $r$ is $$(x-a\cos\theta)^2+(y-b\sin\theta)^2=r^2.$$

Let points of intersection of the circle with the ellipse have parameter values $\phi$, so for a chosen $\theta, a, b$ and $r$ you can find values of $\phi$ by solving
$$(a\cos\phi-a\cos\theta)^2+(b\sin\phi-b\sin\theta)^2=r^2.$$

Comment: And how to solve this equation?

Comment: It will depend on how the equation reduces for given values of $a,b,\theta$ and $r$, but generally one would need to substitute $t=\tan\frac12\phi$ and form and solve a polynomial equation for $t$